# Interpreting matrices as linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      3&4&5\\
      4&5&4
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Could I say that this augmented matrix  forms two different planes ($3x_1 + 4x_2 = 5$ and $4x_1 + 5x_2 = 4$)? And the vector $(x_1,x_2)$ is the vector intersection of those two planes?

Comment: if you are in on two dimensional plane, then $3x + 4y = 5$ is a line. so is $4x+ 5y = 4.$  you are looking for the common point, if it exists, between these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only two rows in the matrix and two columns without the augment, we could say that the augmented matrix represents two different *lines* or two simultaneous linear equations in two unknowns, and the solution of the equations is the intersection point of those two *lines*. There is no need for a plane other than the Euclidean one of all ordered pairs of real numbers.

Comment: Could you say that the two lines form a basis for a plane?

Comment: @JeremyBell: Yes, in particular $\Bbb R^2$, thet set of all ordered pairs of real numbers. This could be generalized to a more general plane, but other generalizations are also possible.